# How to switch ribbon tab programmatically?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I have a ribbon in my view named 'ribbon' that have 2 tabs as below sample codes. I want Button1 when clicked will open Tab2 and vice versa. How would I do this?

```
<ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="ribbon" HelpPaneContent="{x:Static data:WordModel.Help}">
    <ribbon:RibbonTab Header="Tab1" ... >
        <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="Button1" >
            <ribbon:RibbonButton Clicked="SwitchToTab2" />
        </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
    </ribbon:RibbonTab>

    <ribbon:RibbonTab Header="Tab2" ... >
        <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="Button2" >
            <ribbon:RibbonButton Clicked="SwitchToTab1" />
        </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
    </ribbon:RibbonTab>
... 
</ribbon:Ribbon>
```

Comment: Perhaps see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929646/how-to-programmaticaly-select-a-tabitem-in-wpf-tabcontrol/25960172#25960172?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have to trigger the IsSelected property of your tabs

```
private void SwitchToTab1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ribbontab1.IsSelected = true;
        }
    private void SwitchToTab2(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ribbontab2.IsSelected = true;
        }
```

Comment: The ribbonTab.IsSelected = true/false is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Found myself: If your ribbon control named 'Ribbon' then call this in your button's clicked handler:

```
Ribbon.SelectedIndex = indexOfTab;
```

Hope that would help anyone with the same problem with me.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, using:

```
ribbonName.Tabs[TabNumber].IsSelected=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I my opinion that is purely layout related stuff so I would attach an eventhandler to the buttons to change the SelectedTab.