# Go to next tabitem of TabControl wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TabControl with tree TabItems. I have multiple elements in every TabItem. I want to go to the next TabItem when I press the enter key at the last element of the current TabItem.

I use [EnterKeyTraversal attached property](http://madprops.org/blog/enter-to-tab-as-an-attached-property/) for enter key of every element.
How do go to the next TabItem when the enter key were pressed?

Comment: Can you post the code from what you have already tried?

Comment: You can try solutions from these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929646/how-to-programmaticaly-select-a-tabitem-in-wpf-tabcontrol/25960172#25960172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add a `PreviewKeyDown` handler for the last `TextBox` in each `TabItem` and then switch to the next `TabItem` if the `Enter` key is pressed?:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeValue}" PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

...

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        YourTabControl.SelectedIndex = YourTabControl.SelectedIndex < 
            YourTabControl.Items.Count - 1 ? YourTabControl.SelectedIndex + 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is ok for two tab, but when i add malty tab don't raise event for control in second tab.:(