# WPF, C# - change selected tab by doubleclick on a datagrid's row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol

I have a datagrid which is in a tabcontrol item. 
When i doubleclick the row in the datagrid, i want the tabcontrol to change the tab.

Heres my code:

```
<TabItem
            x:Name="tiDashboard"
            Header="Dashboard"
            Background="White">

            <Grid>
                    <DataGrid
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            x:Name="dgAnzeigeWerk"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                            Margin="0,10,0,249" 
                            HeadersVisibility="Column"
                            RowHeight="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="492">

                        <DataGrid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                <EventSetter Event="Control.MouseDoubleClick" Handler="dgAnzeigeWerk_Row_DoubleClick"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.Resources>

                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Nummer" Binding="{Binding Kostenstellennummer}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Kostenstelle" Binding="{Binding Kostenstelle}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Kosten" Binding="{Binding Kosten}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>

                    </DataGrid>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cbYearWerk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="497,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="cbYearWerk_SelectionChanged"/>
                    <Separator Height="15" Margin="0,-10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
...
```

To change the tabitem i use this code:

```
private void dgAnzeigeWerk_Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        tabControl.SelectedItem = tiUebersicht;
    }
```

But the tab won't change. I tried to do the same code with a button and it worked.
I also tried `tabControl.SelectedIndex = 2` or `tiUebersicht.IsSelected = true` but without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: post please, full code of your `TabControl` and what is `tiUebersicht`?

Comment: `tiUebersicht` is a tabitem of `tabControl`. The TabControl itself is nothing special

Answer (score 3):

Add `e.Handled = true;` to your handler at the end.

```
private void dgAnzeigeWerk_Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl.SelectedItem = tiUebersicht;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Actually selection is changing but its happening very fast and focus is returning back to the one containing `DataGrid`. This can be verified using `SelectionChanged` event of `TabControl`.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing  e.Handled = true; and this was the cause of not working issue

Comment: In my opinion this should accepted as the answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Dispatcher** inside of event.

[Link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929646/how-to-programmaticaly-select-a-tabitem-in-wpf-tabcontrol)

```
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => tiUebersicht.IsSelected = true);
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => tiUebersicht.IsSelected = true);
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => tabControl.SelectedItem = tiUebersicht);
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => tabControl.SelectedItem = tiUebersicht);
```

Comment: why do i have to call the dispatcher on row doubleclick?